# Manual control of serial port pins (TxD and RxD)

Tags: c++, winapi, serial-port

I'm working on some idea connected with RS-232 interface manipulation. I can open this port, configure it, write or read data and do some other things with WinAPI. But I don't know how to control individual pins. Well I can take control of DTR and RTS lines via `EscapeCommFunction` function. But I need to manipulate with TxD and RxD lines ("turn" them "on" or "off", binary). Is this possible in Windows 7?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4768590/176769

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't manipulate the RxD line as it's an input.

You can set the TxD line to be continuously ON or OFF by playing with the com port's break state. `SetCommBreak` and `ClearCommBreak` would be the API functions that let you do that.

---

If only one output has to be activated at a time, you can expand your 3 outputs to 8 outputs by using a decoder chip, such as the [74137](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn54ls137.pdf). Beware of transient outputs while switching inputs.

You can also use a shift register chip (such as the [74164](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74ls164.pdf)) to expand 2 outputs (one clock and one signal) into 8 outputs. You can get even more outputs by daisy-chaining shift registers.

If you decide to use these ICs, make sure you don't overload their inputs. RS-232 voltage levels are not the same as TTL voltage levels. Check the spec sheets. You might have to use clamping diodes, or a RS-232 transceiver.

Another alternative is to use the [parallel port](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_port). The parallel port has 8 bidirectional lines plus a small handful of other control lines. Check out the [Inpout](http://logix4u.net/) and [Uniportio](http://legolas558.iragan.com/index.php?option=content&pcontent=1&task=view&id=20&Itemid=68&-uniportio) libraries on how to access the parallel port from Windows.

Seeing that serial and parallel ports are now obsolete, I think your best bet is to use an USB I/O board. You can find some that are cheaper than a parallel cable. Some of them have terminal blocks that make it easy to interface with your experiment.

Comment: >"You can't manipulate the RxD line as it's an input."
Well... This line is connected to PC, isn't it? So, theoretically, somehow it can be managed, I think.

Thanks for advice with break state - I'll try to do smth with it. May be there is some similar trick to play with RxD...

Comment: The RxD line is controlled by the 16550-compatible UART (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/16550_UART) on your PC's southbridge (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Southbridge_%28computing%29). It is physically wired to be an input only.

Comment: @Mr.D, the designers of the hardware must go to extra work to make a pin configurable. If there's a benefit to doing it that way, or if an existing standard requires it, they'll do it. In this case the RxD pin is *always* used as an input so it wasn't given this flexibility. There's no management possible.

Comment: @Mr.D: Just because it's physically connected doesn't mean it's configurable or can be used as an output. One problem is that many inputs are optoisolated so the only thing inside the PC is essentially an LED to ground, or it's an input to a transistor.